# Checking for numbers in char field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a database where some bright spark decided it was a good idea to store numbers and letters (for no good reason) in a char field.

Now I need to select where the number is below a certain value but obviously get an error due to the existence of letters in some of the records.

I have tried the following

```
select column1
from table1
where ISNUMERIC(column1)=1
AND column1<=16
```

however I get the following error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5.00  ' to data
>   type int.

Now that looks like a number to me so why can't it convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAST column if it is NUMERIC

```
select column1
from table1
where ISNUMERIC(column1)=1
AND CAST(column1 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) <= 16.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in SQL Server.  The correct solution in SQL Server 2012+ is to use `try_convert()`:

```
select column1
from table1
where try_convert(int, column1) <= 16;
```

The problem with your query is that SQL Server (like all other databases) does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `where` clause.  Note that you cannot fix your version by using subqueries or CTEs, because SQL Server reserves the right to rearrange operations when compiling and executing the query.

In earlier versions, you can essentially do the same thing using a `case`:

```
select colum1
from table1
where (case when isnumeric(column1) = 0
            then 999
            else convert(int, column1)
       end) <= 16
```

Note:  both of these assume that the string value is an integer.  If it could be a decimal number, then use the appropriate type for conversion.

Comment: This case statement gives me a sytax error "Incorrect syntax near end, expecting AND,OR or THEN"